# c++ print buffer (integer to string)

Tags: c++, buffer

Code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <locale>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
int main()
{
    HWND handle = FindWindow(0 ,TEXT("window name"));
    if(handle == 0)
    {
             MessageBox(0,TEXT("Failed to find window"),TEXT("Return"),MB_OK);
    }
    else
    {
    DWORD ID;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(handle,&ID);
    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_WRITE|PROCESS_VM_OPERATION , FALSE, ID);
    hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_READ , FALSE, ID);

    if(!hProcess)
    {
        Beep(1000,1000);
    }else {

          int buffer;
        if (ReadProcessMemory(hProcess,(void *)0x00963FC4,&buffer,4,NULL))  
        {
             printf(buffer);
        }
        else  {
            MessageBox(0,TEXT("Could not Read"),TEXT("Return"),MB_OK);
              }

        }CloseHandle(hProcess);
    }

}
```

I tried to make this program that reads memory address,
but I got this error:
IntelliSense: argument of type "int" is incompatible with parameter of type "const char *

I tried printf(buffer);

I tried to make string and also doesn't work.

> string test;

Answer (score 1):

First, try using the correct printf() call with format string:

```
printf("%d", buffer);
```

C is a statically typed language and you cannot do python-like stuff with printf() to output anything you want. The printf() function always prints only the first "const char *" argument allowing to substitute some values in this string according to the rules.

Second, I see the TEXT() macros in your code, so you might be using the Unicode strings in your project setup. If so (you should get link errors 2019/2005 in VC++), you have to use the wprintf() function:

```
wprintf(L"%d", buffer);
```

To print the std::string object you must also convert it to the "const char*". This is done by the string::c_str() call:

```
std::string MyString("Test");
printf("Your string is = %s", MyString.c_str());
```

Comment: To be independent of character width, you can use `_tprintf` with your `TEXT` macros. See [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc7014hz.aspx). By the way, all examples in this answer should work, regardless of whether you use `_UNICODE` or not.